# The column name x was not found in this ResultSet and org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I got this exception when i try to get the list using NamedQuery:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
could not execute query. In detail it shows that 
org.nic.eoffice.mis.core.service.ServiceException: 
org.nic.eoffice.mis.core.service.ServiceException: 
org.nic.eoffice.mis.dao.DAOException: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not 
execute query; SQL [{? = call kermis_monthlyreport(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

and also another error present:The column name count11 was not found in this ResultSet.

```
{@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "MonthlyBuisinesModel", entities =                                                                    @EntityResult(entityClass org.nic.eoffice.mis.efile.model.MonthlyBuisinesModel.class))
@NamedNativeQueries({

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findMonthlyReportModel", query = "{? = call        kermis_monthlyreport(:postdetailid, :fromDate, :toDate, :nature, :department,   :office, :userName, :typeId, :filterQuery, :orderQuery, :startIndex,    :maxResults)}", resultSetMapping = "MonthlyBuisinesModel", callable = true) })}
```

Then I create class named MonthlyBuisinesModel to store the resulset.
Input parameters are passed using property page.
Please provide solution for this exception.

Comment: the exception tells you what wrong is

Comment: what is the first `?` for ?

Comment: By using ? gives the idea about the query

Comment: in the property page it is given as   query.name=findMonthlyReportModel
query.isCallable=true
query.entity=org.nic.eoffice.mis.efile.model.MonthlyBuisinesModel
input.model=org.nic.eoffice.mis.efile.model.MonthlyBuisinesInputModel

Comment: Sir Please help me to solve this issue i didnt get the issue